# @PreAuthorize and RoleHierarchyVoter

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using role hierarchy in Spring Security as in my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7809313/accessdeniedexception-if-using-rolehierarchyimpl). When I try to secure a method with `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")`, I always got AccessDeniedException. However, if I change it to `@Secured("ROLE_USER")` or

```
<protect-pointcut
      expression="execution(* my.package.Class.*(..))"
      access="ROLE_GUEST" />
```

I have no issue. From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785706/whats-the-difference-between-secured-and-preauthorize-in-spring-secu-3/3786581#3786581), both should behave the same except the listed differences. Am I missing something here?

**Edit:**
Here is my configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

  <http entry-point-ref="entryPoint">
    <anonymous enabled="false" />
  </http>

  <beans:bean id="entryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint" />

  <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"
    pre-post-annotations="enabled" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
    <!-- this is disable if I secure with annotation @Secured -->
    <protect-pointcut
      expression="execution(* my.package.Class.*(..))"
      access="ROLE_GUEST" />
  </global-method-security>

  <beans:bean id="accessDecisionManager"
    class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
    <beans:property name="decisionVoters">
      <beans:list>
        <beans:ref bean="roleHierarchyVoter" />
      </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
  </beans:bean>

  <beans:bean id="roleHierarchyVoter"
    class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleHierarchyVoter">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="roleHierarchy" />
  </beans:bean>

  <beans:bean id="roleHierarchy"
    class="org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl">
    <beans:property name="hierarchy">
      <beans:value>
        ROLE_USER > ROLE_GUEST
      </beans:value>
    </beans:property>
  </beans:bean>

  <beans:bean id="userDetailsService"
    class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="enableGroups" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="enableAuthorities" value="false" />
  </beans:bean>

  <authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
    </authentication-provider>
  </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-global-method), you must enable `pre-post-annotations` in your `global-method-security` element: `<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />`. Are you doing that?

Comment: @bluefoot, yes, I added both secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure how your configuration looks like as you are referring to another post. The solution might be simple. Leave out `access-decision-manager-ref` as:

```
<sec:global-method-security
    secured-annotations="enabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
```

In practice, if `Pre*` / `Post*` annotations are being used for method security, a voter-based system is not really necessary. Actually there is no voter for that at all, so all other voters abstain and the access is denied.

Comment: If I remove RoleHierarchyVoter or access-decision-manager-ref, I will get AccessDeniedException.

Comment: @CKLee: please post your full Spring configuration

Comment: @CKLee: Did you disable the `protect-pointcut` where using `@PreAuthorize`? Where is  the `AccessDeniedException` thrown? Please also attach the stacktrace.

Comment: At the very beginning, I have no protect-pointcut at all but only `@PreAuthorize`, then I changed to `protect-pointcut` or `@Secured` only it works.

Comment: @CKLee: Please attach a stacktrace of the `AccessDeniedException` when using `@PreAuthorize`.